# saving SESSION from one page to another

Tags: php, session, instagram

I'm working on an application that is authenticating to Instagram. I'm logged in just fine and im getting my "token" correctly, however moving to another page in my site doesnt not recognize that saved session information. Strangely enough, after about 5-10 minutes that same page that did not get the session information, all of a sudden has it.    I am using

> session_start();

at the beginning of every page.   Heres a few snippets of the code:

```
    session_start();
    $token = false;

if (isset($_SESSION['access_token'])) {

    // user authenticated -> receive and set token
    $token = $_SESSION['access_token'];

        } else {
        // receive OAuth code parameter
        $code = $_GET['code'];

    // authentication in progress?
if (isset($code)) {

    // receive and store OAuth token
    $data = $instagram->getOAuthToken($code);
    $token = $data->access_token;
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $token;

        } else {

    // check whether an error occurred
    if (isset($_GET['error'])) {
    echo 'An error occurred: ' . $_GET['error_description'];
    }
        }

    }

// check authentication
    if ($token === false) {

// authentication failed -> redirect to login
header('Location: index.php');
    } 
    else {

    // store user access token
    $instagram->setAccessToken($token);
```

and on my next page, where im checking to see if the user is logged in, i have this code:

```
    session_start();
    require_once 'instagram.class.php';

    $instagram = new Instagram(array(
    'apiKey'      => 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'',
    'apiSecret'   => 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'',
    'apiCallback' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'
     ));


    // create login URL
    $loginUrl = $instagram->getLoginUrl(array(
    'basic',
    'likes',
     'relationships'
     ));

    $instagram->getAccessToken($token);
    $token = $_SESSION['access_token'];
```

This second page doesnt see the access_token or $token.

And as an FYI, im using this PHP wrapper to make these function calls: https://github.com/cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API

Comment: Probably the browser is caching the page and not hitting the server. Put no-cache headers in the page.

Comment: @developerwjk is probably right, but in case he isn't you may also have to config your `php.ini` file a bit for sessions.

Comment: looks like my page already has the "no cache" in the headers (when i look in firebug).  I'm using a site that has cpanel, could this setting be on in the php global settings?

Comment: Heres what i see: Response Headersview source
Cache-Control no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection close

Comment: Yea i've tried in the file and .htaccess and nothing.  Still having the same issue.